# How to automatically launch needed services and apps?

Tags: erlang

I am writing my first erlang application and I want to do things the way they should be done in the erlang ecosystem. My app depends on ssl, inets services and log4erl application to be already started and as for now I start them manually in the erlang shell. After that I start my app's supervisor that starts other parts. The question is how should I organize things so that there would be no need to start ssl, inets and log4erl manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try Erlang release handling system.

Check docs [here](http://demo.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_handling.html#id2272899).

Comment: You may also look my program at http://github.com/JLarky/eadc-hub it uses GNU-make and release handling but i'm not quite satisfied in current realization.

Answer (score 0):

Also see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492714/combining-an-erlang-otp-application-with-other-dependencies-into-a-single-unit-a) for the explanation and some pointers to tools that make creating the releases easier. Extract below:

> There are a few third-party tools that make creating releases easier, like [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki), [relx](http://erlware.github.io/relx/), [mad](http://synrc.com/apps/mad/), [erlang.mk](http://erlang.mk/), or [builderl](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl) (no documentation for the last one yet, some example usages in those applications: [humbundee](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee), [builderl_sample_project_sc](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl_sample_project_sc)).