# Combining an Erlang OTP application with other dependencies into a single unit application

Tags: erlang

How to integrate an already created erlang OTP application with its dependencies into a single unit so that when the unit is started everything(processes) get started behind the scene?

Comment: What you seek is called a [release](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html). You can [easily build one using rebar3](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically launch needed services and apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252421/how-to-automatically-launch-needed-services-and-apps)

Comment: Thanks Steve. It helps

Answer (score 0):

You specify in the `.app` file which other applications your application depends on, like in [this example](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/lib/humbundee/src/humbundee.app.src#L35). Then you build a release using `reltool:create_target/2` like in [this example](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl/blob/master/src/bld_rel.erl#L227). That function takes the definition of a release as a parameter which looks something like [in this file](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/blob/master/etc/reltool.config#L42). When Erlang VM boots the release it starts all the applications in the correct order.

There are a few third-party tools that make creating releases easier, like [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki), [relx](http://erlware.github.io/relx/), [mad](http://synrc.com/apps/mad/), [erlang.mk](http://erlang.mk/), or [builderl](https://github.com/yoonka/builderl) (no documentation in the last one yet, used by the [application](https://github.com/amiramix/humbundee/tree/master/deps) that I pointed out earlier).